# Isn't this comma unambiguous?

Tags: punctuation

[Source](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/elections-2016/tamil-nadu-elections-2016/news/Veerappan-fan-Periyar-baiter-wants-toddy-as-national-drink/articleshow/51861011.cms)

> Seeman comes from a lower middle-class family, is in touch with grassroots workers, **travels,** with them, eats and stays with them too.

This is from an article in a newspaper. I wondered if there's really any need to put it after **travels**.

Comment: Its a typo. It can't be a matter of style because in "eats and stays with them too" has no comma after *stays*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. It sounds awkward. Since the author is trying to outline how Seeman relates with the grassroots workers, then it makes more sense to say that Seeman "travels with them". If it was intentional, then it seems awkward to me. It is also possible that this comma is a typo.